# SQL Server @@trancount confusion

Tags: sql-server

I had thought I had a good grip on SQL Server transaction behavior and expected return values from `@@trancount`.

In an attempt to test for automatic transaction creation when calling stored procedures from Entity Framework, I created the following test scenario which left me questioning my foundational knowledge.

Here is the setup

```
CREATE TABLE mutation
(
    k int
    v varchar(30)
)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE getTranDepth
AS
    print convert(varchar,@@TRANCOUNT) + ' entry value'
    select @@TRANCOUNT

    print convert(varchar, @@TRANCOUNT) + ' entry post read'

    update mutation
    set v = convert(varchar, getdate())
    where k = @@TRANCOUNT

    print convert(varchar, @@TRANCOUNT) + ' post update'

    select @@trancount, convert(varchar, getdate())
    where not exists (select 1 from mutation where k = @@TRANCOUNT)

    print convert(varchar, @@TRANCOUNT) + ' post fake insert'

    insert mutation(k, v)

    select @@trancount, convert(varchar, getdate())
    where not exists (select 1 from mutation where k = @@TRANCOUNT)

    print convert(varchar, @@TRANCOUNT) + ' post insert'
```

The print statements you see I added in an attempt to understand the weirdness I was seeing..

But then I ran into additional weirdness that I'm hoping someone can help me grok (understand)

If I run the following statements

```
select * from mutation 

exec getTranDepth

select * from mutation 

select @@VERSION
```

I get the following results (I diverted all output to text to make it easier to see the response timing)

```
k,v

(0 row(s) affected)

0 entry value

0

(1 row(s) affected)

0 entry post read

(0 row(s) affected)
0 post update
,
0,Sep  7 2017  3:56PM

(1 row(s) affected)

0 post fake insert

(1 row(s) affected)
0 post insert
k,v
2,Sep  7 2017  3:56PM

(1 row(s) affected)


Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
    Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
(1 row(s) affected)
```

So basically this is performing as I would expect with the printed values of `@@trancount`. But when it's updating the table `@@trancount` seems to have a completely different value. Am I suffering from code blindness? Or is there some behavior I'm not versed in?

Comment: the best I can figure is there has to be some form of implicit transaction performed by sql server when it's actually performing mutations..  but it's only a suspicion from testing.  I don't have clear knowledge or documentation on this.

Comment: I don't have an actual answer, just a best guess for why it might happen: when performing an insert / update / some other statements, SQL server probably starts a transaction to check the integrity of the data being inserted then another transaction to perform the insert. From googling, the best answer I can find is a seemingly non-authoritative answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/df50c8b4-7de4-4b9c-a0e6-bb73d9df0f4f/trancount-query-on-insert?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: This is an interesting question, though. But regardless of what's actually happening, I think the bottom line is that @@trancount isn't a function that was intended for use in inserts/updates/etc. Like many other things in SQL, be wary of how you use it.

Comment: Any triggers on the table, by chance? Also, try to wrap your procedure into a transaction and see how it change things.

Comment: no triggers on the table...  it's vanilla creation script is included with no hidden surprises

Comment: @ZLK interesting link.  good to see someone else observed the same behavior.  the attempted answer is unsettling as it feels like someone doing a math problem by guessing the answer and not showing any work.  based on what we expect @@trancount to do it's simple intuition to say.  "there must be an extra 2 transactions coming from somewhere" since that's the value of @@trancount   but to just restate the problem as they did and say something akin to "it's obvious" is either the least helpful type of professor or a student bluffing on an exam with no way to tell the difference between the two.

Comment: ... and the "it's obvious path" explaination fails since if it were really obvious then all the selects I have done one would expect to generate an @@trancount value of 1...  since they don't the insert by itself either generates 2 by itself or changes the behavior of it's select to generate 1 when in the context of an insert.   *either* way  NOT OBVIOUS

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenss/2010/07/10/usage-of-trancount-in-dml-statements/ SQL Creates a top-level transaction before running the DML statement if one does not exist, then the DML statement is run in a nested transaction.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft that blog entry is the most on point item yet.  good job finding it.   I have slightly adjusted the query from it to get the following query which helps us to make educated guesses about where the transaction thresholds are

Comment: ;with test as
(
select 
  OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) objectName
 ,f.*
 ,p.*
from fn_dblog(null,null) f
 left join sys.partitions p on f.PartitionId = p.partition_id
) 

select top 5000 * from test
where [Transaction ID] in 
(select [Transaction ID] from test where objectname= 'mutation')
order by [Transaction ID], [Current LSN]

derived from query at [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenss/2010/07/10/usage-of-trancount-in-dml-statements/)